# ConstraintLayout with Button State Pressed

Tags: java, android

I have a button that is complex but can be done easily with Constrain Layout. However I would like button state change feature to change the background color when pressed. I tried with state press or selected, but it doesn't work. What's the best way to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_grayout" />
</selector>
```

ConstraintLayout as a Button

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
    android:id="@+id/background_create"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Big Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mini Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#D5D5D5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_display_alert1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to add  android:clickable="true" and android:focusable="true" to your ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `onClick` event to the ConstraintLayout like following:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
    android:id="@+id/background_create"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    >
 ....
```

add `onClick()` in the activity or fragment

Answer (score 0):

As you apply the drawable to the `ConstraintLayout`, not to a `Button`; then you have to make it clickable and focusable in order to have the press effect of the `Button`:

So, you need to add:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_press"
    android:id="@+id/background_create"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="8dp">
```